# Encrypted header param with the X-requested-with header value

Tags: security, nginx, web, webview, http-headers

I have a web application which is mostly for a mobile audience. We have our promotion links hosted on various publisher sites which send traffic to us from 3rd party android apps by loading the site in a Webview.

Of late we have been seeing some inconsistencies in the headers that is received at our nginx.

[Sample logs for the request at our Nginx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rARe.png)

Is there a reason why the header key is coming as **6yu5sfdsqlbatwoc**=com.android.settings ?

Or is this a spoofing of the x-requested header and considered as a CSRF Attack?